# create-next-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, react-i18next

I'm trying to install next app with `npx create-next-app nextjs-blog` and i keep getting this error;

> 'create-next-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

I've been stucked since friday and haven't gotten w befitting solution, pls help out.
I just started learning next js Nd I'm not sure why I'm getting this error over and over.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled my node the error still persist

Comment: Please  add your error logs also.

Comment: Looks like per next.js docs - https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/create-next-app, you should be using `npx create-next-app@latest` - though I just used create-next-app and it works fine, so it is probably a local path issue

Comment: What version of node are you using? (Check with `node -v`)

Comment: latest, i just installed it again yesterday

Answer (score 0):

First Install This:

```sh
npm i -g create-next-app
```

Then:

```sh
create-next-app
```

Answer (score 0):

From NextJs docs:

```
npx create-next-app@latest.
```

Answer (score 0):

command :

> yarn create next-app

reference : https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/create-next-app

Answer (score 0):

First we need to install npm i -g create-next-app.

Add the path variable in system.
C:\Users{User_name}\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 0):

My issue on windows 10 was for some reason my environment variables, specifically the path user variable, had gotten many variables duplicated, exceeing the max 4096 limit without telling me. I manually deleted a bunch of duplicates and then saving it worked without the max limit reached error. I then refreshed my environment variables, closed all terminals, and then create-next-app worked.